# How to change the end of the text content of an lxml etree.Element in Python3?

Tags: python, html, nlp, lxml, elementtree

I am currently working on a natural language processing project in Python. We have html texts of scientific articles, which we parse with Pythons lxml.etree, and store as Elements and ElementTrees. Some of our html texts are actually converted pfs using pdf2htmlEX (https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX). This converter turns every row of the article into a div, in a way that strips spaces from endlines.

So this html:

```
<div>This is a</div>
<div>sample text.</div>
```

... gets parsed like this:

> This is asample text.

Notice the absence of whitsepace between 'a' and 'sample'.

I need it to look like this:

> This is a sample text.

I have to somehow add the whitespace manually to the end of the line. Etree does have an Element.text attribute, and Element.text can be changed as any other strings could be. Element.text += ' ' results with adding whitespace to the end of the .text. However, .text will only go until the first child tag. Consider the following code:

```
html = '<div>This is a <strong>sample</strong> text.</div>'
el = etree.fromstring(html)
print(el.text)
```

The printed result is:

> 'This is a '

Sadly, Element does not have an attribute to reach the **end** of the text. If you want to use the whole text content of an Element, you need to use ''.join(el.itertext()). Sadly, for a couple of reasons, I need to change the elements text content directly. Storing the results of the itertext and using it in the rest of the code is **not an option** for me at this time.

To add some further challange, there are different variations of the same problem:

```
html_1 = <div>This is a <strong>sample</strong> text.</div>
html_2 = <div>This is a sample <strong>text.</strong></div>
```

These are different cases: html_1 has the endline in the div element, while html2 has it in the strong.

Is there a solution where I can add a space to the end of the string in an Element?

Comment: It might help you to understand the `tail` property of an element, which holds the text after the element's end tag, but before the next sibling element's start tag. It is well described here: https://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pylxml/web/etree-view.html.

Comment: Thank you, that absolutely solved my problem!